# White stripe when exporting QgsLayout Map to image

Tags: pyqgis, export, image, layouts, qgsmapcanvas

I have a problem when I try to export a Map in the Layout of QGIS 3 with the Python API. Here is my code :

```
qpt = QDomDocument()
qpt.setContent(content)
layout = QgsLayout(QgsProject().instance())
layout.loadFromTemplate(qpt, QgsReadWriteContext())
mapItem = layout.referenceMap()
layoutExporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
imageSettings = layoutExporter.ImageExportSettings()
imageSettings.dpi = 150
imageSettings.generateWorldFile = 1
path = "path/to/my/iamge.tif"
layoutExporter.exportToImage(path, settings=imageSettings)
```

When I export my layout's map I get an image with a white stripe at the bottom like in the following file :

[image]

The width of the stripe is variable when for example a widget (like the python console) is opened or not. It seams that the map of the layout doesn't fill its whole surface because its ratio is not the same as the map canvas' one.

Is there a way to say to the layout's map to fill completely ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use `zoomToExtent()` instead of `setExtent()` so the right line is :

```
mapItem.zoomToExtent(mapCanvas.extent())
```

`setExtent()` sets the exact same extent as `mapCanvas` (the extent is a `QgsRectangle` with 4 summits which have the coordinates of the 4 angles of `mapCanvas`).

`zoomToExtent()` : if the ratio width/height of `mapCanvas` is lower than `mapItem`'s ratio, then QGIS will complete the white stripe from `setExtent()` with not displayed information.